# To compare textbox values

Tags: c#

I have to plot a graph based on some values.I have to validate whether the values entered are in ascending order.9 textboxes and a submit button is there.
This is a windows application using c#.

If unsorted values are entered ,a message " Enter values in ascending order" should be displayed while clicking submit button.

**Current Code**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    int[] arraynumber = new int[10]; 
    arraynumber[0] = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); 
    arraynumber[1] = int.Parse(textBox2.Text); 
    if (arraynumber[0] > arraynumber[1]) 
    { 
      MessageBox.Show("Enter values in ascending order"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you share your attempted code ?

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] arraynumber = new int[10];
            arraynumber[0] = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            arraynumber[1] = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            if (arraynumber[0] > arraynumber[1])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter values in ascending order");
            }
        }

Comment: how to compare with all  9 textboxes

Comment: Thanks for the code, have added my answer. Kindly let me know if it helped in resolving your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var txts = new List<TextBox> {textBox1, textBox2, textBox3};
    for (var i = 1; i < txts.Count; i++)
        if (int.Parse(txts[i - 1].Text) > int.Parse(txts[i].Text))
            MessageBox.Show("Enter values in ascending order");
}
```

Comment: You must customize it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One key decision you need to take is how to assign an order to these TextBox Controls. Let's assume that they are ordered by their Name, though I would suggest you use the Tag Property to assign priority.Or build an array of TextBox in same order as you require the evaluation

**Case 1 :**

If you Form does not have any other TextBox other than the ones concerned, you can select all controls of TextBox and parse value assigned to it, into an Array. Later, you can verify that the array is in increasing order.

```
 var listOfValues = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().OrderBy(x=>x.Name).Select(x=> Convert.ToInt32(x.Text));

 var isIncreasing = listOfValues.Aggregate((a, i) => a >= i ? Int32.MaxValue : i) != Int32.MaxValue;
 if (!isIncreasing)
                MessageBox.Show("Enter values in ascending order");
```

**Case 2:**

If you have other TextBox in the Form other than the ones concerned, then you need to take couple of additional steps.

First, you need to create an Array of TextBoxes which comprises of the ones you are concerned about.

```
var listOfTextBoxes = new[] { textBox1, textBox2,........ };
```

Then you can parse values of TextBoxes as in earlier case.

```
var listOfValues = listOfTextBoxes.Select(x=> Convert.ToInt32(x.Text));
var isIncreasing = listOfValues.Aggregate((a, i) => a >= i ? Int32.MaxValue : i) != Int32.MaxValue;
if (!isIncreasing)
            MessageBox.Show("Enter values in ascending order");
```